# something wrong with my code in listview android

Tags: android, eclipse, listview

i'm trying to put a listview with images and texts
 here's my code

```
package com.example.listview;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Sira extends Activity {

    private List<Kisas> stories = new ArrayList<Kisas>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sira);
        //Generates ListItems
        //Ctrl+1 to create the method from here
        PopulateStories();
        //To Show Items in ListView
        PopulateListView();
    }

    private void PopulateStories() {
        stories.add(new Kisas("Said bn 3amer Al Jam7i",1999,R.drawable.user,"needling work"));
        stories.add(new Kisas("Abu Tal7a Al Ansari",1999,R.drawable.personal,"needling work"));
        stories.add(new Kisas("Al Bara2 bn Malek Al Ansari",1999,R.drawable.smile,"needling work"));
        stories.add(new Kisas("Abu Ayoub Al Ansari",1999,R.drawable.ic_launcher,"needling work"));    
    }

    private void PopulateListView() {
        ArrayAdapter<Kisas> arrayadapter = new MyListAdapter();//we named it mylistadapter
        ListView List= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_Stories);
        List.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
    }

    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Kisas>{
        public MyListAdapter() {
            super(Sira.this,
                R.layout.item_view,stories);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View item_View= convertView;

            if(item_View ==null){
                item_View = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent ,false); 
            }
            Kisas currentStory= stories.get(position);
            ImageView imageview= (ImageView) item_View.findViewById(R.id.item_Icon)  ;
            imageview.setImageResource(currentStory.getIconId());
            TextView makeText = (TextView) item_View.findViewById(R.id.item_textMake);
            makeText.setText(currentStory.getMake());
            TextView yearText = (TextView) item_View.findViewById(R.id.item_textYear);
            yearText.setText(""+ currentStory.getYear()); //Lezem 7awela la string
            TextView conditionText = (TextView) item_View.findViewById(R.id.item_textCondition);
            conditionText.setText(currentStory.getCondition());
            return item_View;
        }
    }
}
```

it's giving me an error in the method PopulateListView

anyone can help?

what i know is that the code is in these lines:

```
private void PopulateListView() {
    ArrayAdapter<Kisas> arrayadapter = new MyListAdapter();//we named it mylistadapter
    ListView List= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_Stories);
    List.setAdapter(arrayadapter);    
}

private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Kisas> {
    public MyListAdapter() {
        super(Sira.this, R.layout.item_view,stories);
    }
}
```

i'm new at android so i followed the steps show in the following video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WRANgDgM2Zg

Comment: Which error? Please share stacktrace.

Comment: how can i do that :$ cant copy paste it

Comment: Well, at least the name of the exception and the line that throws it would be helpful.

Comment: Level:E
Tag: AndroidRuntime
text: at com.example.listview.Sira.PopulateListView(Sire.java :50)

Comment: Mmh that's actually not the exception itself, it should appear above that. Anyway, which line is line 50?

Comment: List.setAdapter(arrayadapter);

Comment: what is written above that:
 caused by java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting a `NullPointerException`, the call to

```
findViewById(R.id.listView_Stories);
```

is definitely returning `null`. Please, double check that there's no typo in your id name, and that there's actually a view called `listView_Stories` in your layout xml.

PS: be careful with the naming conventions, you'll probably have less confusions if you stick to *camelCase* (i.e. `listViewStories` instead of `listView_Stories`)